# NgModel binding doesn't work inside <form> for Jasmine test

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular5, jasmine2.0

In my Angular 5.2.0 project, I have the following structure:

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private _title = 'initial value';
  public get title(): string {
    return this._title;
  }
  public set title(v: string) {
    this._title = v;
  }
}
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```js
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should bind an input to a property', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Update the title input
    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name="title"]')).nativeElement;
    inputElement.value = 'new value';
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(app.title).toEqual('new value');
    });
  }));
});
```

And for the following test passes:

**app.component.html**

```html
<input name="title" type="text" [(ngModel)]="title">
```

But if I put the input into form tag, test fails:

**app.component.html**

```html
<form>
  <input name="title" type="text" [(ngModel)]="title">
</form>
```

*Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0) AppComponent should bind an input to a property FAILED
        Expected 'initial value' to equal 'new value'.*

Any idea why it is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution (using fakeAsync + tick):

```
it('should bind an input to a property', fakeAsync(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name="title"]')).nativeElement;
  inputElement.value = 'new value';
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  expect(app.title).toEqual('new value');
}));
```

Second solution (using sync and a little code refactoring):

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let app: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({...}).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges(); // this call is required
  }));

  it('should bind an input to a property', async(() => {
    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name="title"]')).nativeElement;
    inputElement.value = 'new value';
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(app.title).toEqual('new value');
    });
  }));
  ...
```

> Any idea why it is happening?

According to [official Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#async-vs-sync):

> Template-driven forms delegate the creation of their form controls to directives. To avoid changed after checked errors, these directives take more than one cycle to build the entire control tree. That means you must wait until the next change detection cycle happens before manipulating any of the controls from within the component class.
>
> For example, if you inject the form control with a @ViewChild(NgForm) query and examine it in the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook, you'll discover that it has no children. You must trigger a change detection cycle using setTimeout() before you can extract a value from a control, test its validity, or set it to a new value.

p.s. Also there was a similar issue (dispatchEvent doesn't trigger ngModel changes #13550) in [Angular's GitHub repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13550#issuecomment-267811613), you can also check it out.

Comment: So it worked actually, but I still don't get it why moving `const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent); const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance; fixture.detectChanges();` from `it` (as in my example) to `beforeEach` (in your second solution)  does the trick.

Comment: Yep, good question. Probably there is some tick delay between `beforeEach` and starting `it` function.  But I'm not sure - what's actually going on here.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I had just not put tick() after detectChanges() and that would cause failure in my case. Putting tick() after initializing fixture (basically before changing the data), fixed the issue.

Comment: First example does not work: `Expected undefined to equal 'new value'.`